# Are perpendicular bisectors of an arbitrary $n$-gon concurrent ? If so, how to prove it?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Are perpendicular bisectors of an arbitrary $n$-gon concurrent ? If so, how to prove it ?

Comment: Surely you mean a *regular* $n$-gon, right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг No, I mean arbitrary convex polygon. It is okay, I just realized they won't be.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Sorry, they maybe. I am not sure.

Comment: Exactly, I think even for $n=4$ it won't be the case. In fact, thinking of it now, can you find a (convex) quadrilateral where two of the perpendicular bisectors are in fact *parallel*? (So that these two, and therefore all of them cannot meet). Think of something trapezium like

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Ah! Thanks.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Your name reminds me of a friend of mine. He is doing a PhD in mathematics now. His name was also Ravichandran Iyer and he also liked to write stuff in Russian. And he liked football as well.

Comment: Interesting how so many details seem to match. I think, with high probability, I am your friend. My first name is сарвеш (now how do you say that?)

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Wonderful. You are Sarvesh from IISc.

Comment: I was in IISc, now I am somewhere else, but you are correct!To be frank I cannot guess who you are, and for some reason I'd actually like to continue guessing! Also, +1.

Comment: I actually thought it might be you! How are you doing? I am now fully into Stochastic PDE, and it also turns out my main focus at first is on the KPZ equation, which apparently has some applications in conformal field theory. I am wondering if you have come across it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** What does it mean for all perpendicular bisectors of an $n-$gon $A_1A_2...A_n$ to be concurrent at $P$?

Well, it means, that all segments $PA_1, PA_2, ..., PA_n$ are equal in length. Why?

[image]

Observe that the triangles $\triangle A_1A_2P, \triangle A_2, A_3P...$ are all isosceles since $P$ lies on their perpendicular bisector. All of them being isosceles means that $$A_1P=A_2P\quad A_2P=A_3P\quad A_3P=A_4P...\implies A_1P=A_2P=A_3P=A_4P=...$$

$P$ is thus the circumcentre of the $n-$ gon.

> But this is only possible if you polygon is $\color{blue}{cyclic}$

Comment: Agreed, thank you.

Comment: @user44690 I edited the answer to make one statement clearer

Comment: @user44690 Please consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it helped you ;)